# Trying to automate Instagram login

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does anybody know how to automate the login to Instagram using python. I'm just not getting the hang of it. Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time

PATH = 'C:\Python27\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

driver.maximize_window()

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys('#####')
username.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

search = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
search.send_keys('######')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Hi Ayo, what is your question here? Did you get an error or do you just look for a feedback? If your code isn't working, give a look at this example using selenium as well (https://pythonbaba.com/python-code-to-automate-instagram-login/). XPATH are updated often so web-scraping isn't the best solution. But if you don't have any API to use there isn't many other solutions...

Comment: I got an error.

Comment: Could you share the error message on your post to help us understand what happened exactly?